# Getting total sum of previous 3 month record

Tags: mysql

I need to get the total sum of the mark of previous 3 months. that is if I look on April I would get the sum of Jan, Feb, Mar. Similarly, When I look on Jan it displays the total of previous year Oct, Nov, Dec. I use the below query

```
SELECT empid,
       name,
       sum(total) AS total
FROM formresult
WHERE (MONTH(date) = MONTH(now())
       OR MONTH(date) = MONTH(now()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
       OR MONTH(date) = MONTH(now()- INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
  AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(now())
GROUP BY empid
```

But when using this code I got 3-month result but when I look on Jan it does not display previous year result. How could it possible. Please Help me

Comment: What columns does the table formresult have and what type are they?

Comment: id int autoinrement, empid int, name varchar(30), total(int),date date

Comment: The part ```AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(now())``` will prevent you from spanning to a previous year. As shown in one of the answers, you could use the BETWEEN function instead of the multiple OR statements. Lastly, the three month checks will return the current month, the previous month, and the one before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you need.

```
SELECT empid, name, SUM(total) AS total
FROM formresult
WHERE date BETWEEN
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') AND
  LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
GROUP BY empid
```

See [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), and [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I got it, Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues with the date math that's being done here. First it looks like you are getting the current month and previous two months instead of the previous three months. This is getting you the current month `MONTH(date) = MONTH(now())`. Also you can't assume it's the current year, if you run this on January you'd expect to get October, November and December of the previous year however it will return for the current year.

Comment: yeah.. I got it. But the form should mark on each current month. ie. The only mark for Jan should put on Jan itself, similarly in each month. when I mark for 3 months, then I check the mark only after 3 months that is the 4th month, In this case, when I mark on oct nov dec, I check the total mark on Jan. But actually, I don't know the code for it.

Comment: Looks like the response from @fubar is what you need for the date math, here's the manual reference to the function used in that answer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub